# Javascript & Fabric js : how to call object outside its function in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, object, fabricjs

Please take a look at my code : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/341/)

I want to *stop clipping an image when the image is being selected* and then *clip it back again when the image is not selected*. But I don't know **how to call each object correctly in fabric js**.

Let's see what is in my Jsfiddle. You don't have to read them all.

- **Line119 - Line129 is the example part** showing what I want to do. You can see that it was done only for `pugImg`. Please mention this
  part is just for example so there is a problem that when you click
  the `logo`, `pugImg` will be called too. (don't mind about it. Your
  answer would be the solution to fix this anyway). *So, after you
  understand my point, please delete this part.*
- **Line135 - Line142 is the *Pseudo-code* where I want to finish**. Similar to my example, but now, I would like to create those events
  outside their function so that I can use only one code of events for
  all objects.

**The question is**, how to finish Line 135-142?

Sorry for English and the question for being too wide, please feel free to suggest an edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this fiddle for an updated "clipByName" code, cleaner and easier to use.

You also find solution for your question.
I stored a reference to last select object in a canvas property.

```
canvas.on("object:selected", function (e) {
    e.target.clipTo = null;
    if (canvas.lastSelected && e.target != canvas.lastSelected) {
        canvas.lastSelected.clipTo = clipByName;
    }
    canvas.lastSelected = e.target;
});
canvas.on("selection:cleared", function (e) {
     canvas.lastSelected.clipTo = clipByName;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/342/